# jQuery selecting all elements without a certain tag in them

Tags: jquery, slideup

```
$('.products .product-category[data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').slideDown();
```

I have the above selector but I am trying to add another selector elsewhere that select all **BUT** `[data-slug="'+slug+'"]` and slide them up using `.slideUp()`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**:not selector**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('.products .product-category:not([data-slug="'+slug+'"]) .expander').slideUp()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('.products .product-category').not('[data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').slideUp();
```

---

[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('.products .product-category:not([data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').slideUp();
```

---

[Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

```
$('.products .product-category[data-slug!="'+slug+'"] .expander').slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('.products').not('.product-category[data-slug="'+slug+'"] .expander').slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.not()`:

```
$('.products .product-category').not('[data-slug="'+slug+'"]').find('.expander').slideUp();
```